# Inputting custom hOCR output into (py)tesseract OCR to format into readable text

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

Is it possible to format hOCR generated by other OCR algorithms (e.g. EasyOCR), and then provide these into tesseract, from there continuing the process with text segmentation into a final textual output?

I currently have the plain bounding boxes for words/phrases on the photos, but need to segment this into a plain text whilst preserving the  structure (such as by using `--psm 1` with tesseract).

Alternatively, is there a fairly straightforward way to convert hOCR into plain text whilst preserving the document's structure (i.e. spacing between letters, columns/rows...)

Many thanks

Comment: I have found but not yet tested some libraries (e.g. HocrCoverter, hocr-tools). There is a good wikipedia page on hOCR too. But do you have a tool for converting the raw bounding boxes from (e.g. EasyOCR) into an hOCR file? Or do you manually piece them together? Then the pipeline could be reconstructed with the combination of these.